# On Teams on the mobile site, the link to my profile from the top right dropdown goes to my main Stack Overflow profile

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams

On the normal mobile if I am at the homepage or other parts of a Team:

[image]

And I click on the top right button, I get a link to my SO profile:

[image]

However, on the responsive mobile, if I am at the Teams site and click on my icon:

[image]

I get sent to my [Charcoal profile](https://stackoverflow.com/c/charcoal/users/98). Testing this link on the mobile site, it is designed for mobile devices, so there’s no technical limitation:

[image: The mobile version of a Teams profile]